# FTP listing files (ls) with dynamic date YYYMMDD pattern

Tags: ls, filenames, date, ftp, qnap

Following a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875115/supplying-dynamic-pattern-yyyymmdd-as-ftp-mget-pattern) I'm trying to list the files on an FTP server that match a pattern, as shown below

```
event_date=`date +%Y%m%d`   
ftp -n XX.XX.XX.XX <<END_SCRIPT
ls *${event_date}* todays_files.dat
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Is there a way to list these files, apart from listing all files and grep'ing on the client side i.e.

```
event_date=`date +%Y%m%d`
ftp -n XX.XX.XX.XX <<END_SCRIPT
ls * all_files.dat
quit
END_SCRIPT
grep $event_date all_files.log > todays_files.dat
```

Comment: Does not work in what way? The `ls` in FTP will expand globs. What do you get vs what do you expect? It seems like you're expecting your `ls` command in the here-document to redirect to some output file (todays_files.dat or all_files.dat) but as-written you're asking ftp's `ls` to list that file on the remote side. Intended?

Comment: @JeffSchaller In the original snippet `todays_files.dat` is empty i.e. no files are listed. If however I write `ls *20190709* today_files.dat` , `todays_files.dat` contains files on the FTP server whose names contain the substring "20190709".

Comment: Ahh; I get a prompt to output the results (`output to local-file`); your FTP client must automatically assume that action.  Do you have a peculiar FTP client?

Comment: @JeffSchaller All of the above commands are executed in a bash script. The client ftp is the standard client that shipped with the distro (a NAS box). The server is running proftp.

Comment: What NAS system (or distribution) is this?

Comment: It's a QNAP box. I don't know what distro it runs.

Comment: This seems (to me) like important information, to help answerers understand what software we're dealing with. Could you please edit that information into the question? Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95912/discussion-between-olumide-and-jeff-schaller).

Comment: I get the same behavior  on a Centos 7 machine, so its unlikely to be caused by the distro of the NAS device.

Comment: My ftp client says `ls` is used to list a directory given by name, not a file. You could try `mls` to list a file glob pattern such as you have.

Comment: @meuh `mls *${event_date}*` does not work. I've gone with listing all files and filtering out the those that match the date YYYYMMDD.